# Make booking(woocommerce-booking) exactly equal to order id(woocommerce)?

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

i need a way to get the woocommerce-booking id to be exactly equal to the woocommerce order id?

I also want them to increment by 1 sequentially?

Comment: I'll reuse a comment from another post: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question, and the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: This is simply not possible as an order can have many bookings.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that can't be done. Bookings and Orders are both 'posts' so the ID's for both of them are saved in the same table in the database, and the ID's must be unique.